# How to install and use a new font in joomla

Tags: fonts, joomla, joomla1.5

I need in one of my clients site to use the font they buy recently. I am using CMS JOOMLA and confused how to install this new font (Its in .ttf format). I read some articles while goggling that if we use font in joomla the user should also have the font installed in the system to view it.

Please guide me how to install the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better alternative to use CSS. The only implication is that you need to have the font licenced for use on the web:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/04/13/quick-and-easy-css-font-face-code/

This is supported across most browsers and is much simpler to implement than sIFR.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/typography/11243

Answer (score -1):

You don't install fonts on your website, if you want the text on your site to show up in a non-standard font every visitor has to have it on their local machine.

It's easiest to stick to the standard fonts, and any small amounts of text you want in a special font you have to make as images.

If you are still not satisfied then have a look here: http://novemberborn.net/2006/12/sifr3beta1-110

Beware it is a mission!